# How to apply overlay to certain elements based on choices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four different buttons on a page, each sitting under product description that relates to that button. These buttons are for the users to click their favorite product. When they click one button, it would be preferred for the other three buttons to be given an overlay, or other visual that makes it look like they were disabled from being chosen. Is there a simple way of doing this?? Maybe with CSS or javascript?

I am new to Javascript and would appreciate any help!! Thanks!

Edited 12/18/14:
My apologies, let me add some code.

HTML:

```
<div id="blue-btn-grades">THIS IS MY FAVE</div>
```

CSS: I have media queries so CSS may be different for specific resolution but below CSS is for my 17" computer monitor.

```
#blue-btn-grades {
font-family: BigNoodle;
font-size: 18px;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #3095b4;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 90px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Please let me know if you need anything else!

Update: 2/18/14 -
In my original post, I said button but more specifically, I would prefer this overlay to be applied to the entire div. The HTML for one div is below:

```
<a name="grades"><div class="col-lg-3" align="center"><img src="images/golden.png" /><br /><h5>Golden with Delicate Taste</h5><h6>Usually made at the beginning of the new maple season. Pour over vanilla ice cream for a Vermont maple sundae, sometimes called the Sugarmakers’ Favorite Dessert.</h6><div id="blue-btn-grades">THIS IS MY FAVE</div><a href="http://vermontmaple.org/maple-products/" title="Maple Products | Vermont Maple Sugar Makers Association" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'external link', 'buy button golden grades page', 'vermontmaple.org/maple-products', {'nonInteraction': 1});" target="_blank"><div id="teal-btn-grades">BUY ME SOME!</div></a></div></a>
```

Thanks again everyone. I need to learn javascript...

Comment: I would say you need CSS *and* Javascript...

Comment: If you posted code, you would get a better answer, more specific to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, and no CSS...

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pbQGP/1/

HTML:

```
<button>First</button>
<button>Second</button>
<button>Third</button>
<button>Fourth</button>
```

JS:

```
$("button").on('click', function(){
    $("button").not(this).attr({disabled: "disabled"})
})
```

Comment: @Billy Moon. I added the code you suggested. Let me know if there is enough. When I added the JS into my header tag with <script> tag, it did give my buttons I made through CSS another button style, but it did not disable the buttons that were not chosen. I am not sure if it's because of the additional CSS or if I setup incorrectly? Thanks for the help!